# How to check if a value exist in other pandas columns which contains several values separated by comma

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have problem with my data. So I want to check a value for column A in column B which contains several values separated by comma. The result that I want is when the value is exist, it will fill column C with True, otherwise it will fill with False.

Sample table like this:

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A,B,C,AA,BB,CC | True |
| B | A,AA,BB,CC | False |
| C | A,B,C | True |

I already use something like this `.apply(lambda x: x.Column_A in x.Column_B, axis=1)` but it resulted the second row as True because it detect B from BB. Basically my script doesn't the comma as separator for different value.

Any solution for my problem?

Comment: I assume you mean `ket` and `ID_WPP` are the equivalent of `Column_A` and `Column_B` in your example. Perhaps it might be better to use the latter so that the example makes sense when future viewers look at the question. This might require that jezrael slightly change his answer too.

Comment: Oh yeah I am sorry I forgot to rename the column names. Will edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['Column_C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Column_A in x.Column_B.split(','), axis=1)
```

Comment: it worked! I need to make adjustment on column_B because it contains space.

Comment: @le_camerone - why you post same answer after 30 minutes later like me?

Comment: @jezrael because your columns didn't follow the dummy dataframe. I did comment above. I'm happy to withdraw my answer if you rename the columns in your answer.

Comment: @le_camerone - If check original question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71823495/revisions) there is solution `.apply(lambda x: x.Ket in x.ID_WPP, axis=1)` so it is reason why used this columns

Comment: @RidwanNurzeha please unaccept my answer and accept jezarel's answer as they submitted first.

Answer (score 1):

Use `split`:

```
df['Column_C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Column_A in x.Column_B.split(', '), axis=1)
```

If performance is important use list comprehension:

```
df['Column_C'] = [a in b.split(', ') for a, b in zip(df.Column_A, df.Column_B)]
```

Comment: @RidwanNurzeha - Only one answer should be accpeted.

Comment: And you just have `.apply`. Shouldn't is be `df.apply`.

Comment: @le_camerone - not possible, because accepted. If different columns names I think it is not reason for new answer.

Comment: I apologise. I'm new to this so next time I will comment on your answer before making a new one.

Comment: @le_camerone - No problem, I was only surprised. Thank you for explanation. Happy coding!